# Is the Salesforce Marketing Cloud reporting API the same as the standard Salesforce reporting API?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Been googling but slightly confused about Pardot vs SF Marketing Cloud vs Salesforce.

Is the same reporting API for standard SF the same as the reporting API for Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific reporting API available for Marketing Cloud. You can use [Tracking Extracts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) to provide engagement data to external systems:

> Tracking extracts provide granular tracking data for import from Email Studio into external systems. Use tracking extracts to export granular data regarding several different aspects of email send jobs, such as clicks, bounces, and survey data, from Marketing Cloud. Then, import that information into an automation or system

Comment: You can also use out of the box reports that Marketing Cloud provides https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_standard_reports.htm&type=5 . These are very easy to create and provide nearly all the tracking data as per business requirement.